# Quantizing highly nonlinear field-theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, non-linear-systems, quantization

I'm wondering how to go about quantizing a classical field theory which looks nothing like a free field theory plus a perturbation term. Suppose for concreteness I have the classical hamiltonian $ \mathcal{H} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\sqrt{1+P^2}  $, where $ Q(x,t) $ is a field and $ P(x,t) $ is its canonically conjugate momentum. Suppose also I know how to solve the classical field theory to find explicit solutions.

My naive understanding is I can just take $ Q $ and $ P $ to be operator valued fields with canonical commutation relations. Similarly I can take $ \mathcal{H} $ and other functions of $ Q $ and $ P $ to be operators, and this defines an algebra. There are ordering ambiguities but suppose I just choose an ordering for the operator $ \mathcal{H} $ and other relevant quantities.

The problem is I don't know how to actually calculate anything with this. I understand in principle if I have an algebra that says a lot about the system and I can for instance construct the GNS representation (there may be mathematical subtleties I'm overlooking here). But I'm not sure if concretely this is the best way to think about things.

Does anybody know of a 'standard' approach, or can point me to a paper or textbook?

Comment: I can't help with the answer, but you have made me curious: what are the explicit solutions of the classical field theory?

Comment: It was just a Hamiltonian picked to illustrate what I meant by 'highly nonlinear'. But it is a simplified version of Hamiltonians I'm studying where the contour lines or isosurfaces of the Q field themselves move as classical strings or branes.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that's where it was going, but I was hoping that this would turn out to be some well understood toy model.

Answer (score 2):

the straight forward quantization is blocked due to the singularity of the lagrangian. search for WKB method in connection with solitons.

Answer (score 1):

One 'standard' approach to quantization which always works is the path integral:
\begin{equation}
\langle \mathcal O \rangle = \frac{\int [dQ dP] \mathcal O\exp \left( \int dx dt (\mathcal H + i P \dot Q)\right)}{\int [dQ dP] \exp \left( \int dx dt (\mathcal H + i P \dot Q)\right)}
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal O$ is whatever operator you are interested in.

Comment: The argument of the exponential should be $i \int (P\dot{Q}-\mathcal{H})$. I would personally choose the differential to be $d^4 x$.

Comment: Well there is still the matter of the choice of the stochastic integral for the action, which corresponds to the choice of operator ordering